# Import data from more than one line in Excel to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008, csv

I have some data to import from Excel into SQL Server, the problem I have is the data in Excel is on more than one line, so I can't simply Save As... to CSV and import as normal, does anyone have any tips for how I would go about it. Here is an example of an item of data to import:

Contact Telephone   Email   Code        Client Nº
miss samantha sheldon   9999999999  sama@aaaaaa.com     Unprocessed     Not set 
Address madeup st, madeup town, United Kingdom 
Comments

Many thanks in advance